# NUXT / GRIDSOME - how they handle updating content?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, gridsome

My questions revolves around how GRIDSOME or NUXT handles new content from the point of view of an SEO crawler.

I'm planning a project that will include blog posts and page content that will update.

currently using vue - if a CMS is generating the content on the fly updated content is pulled into the users browser via a fetch request.

using NUXT / GRIDSOME - they (to my knowledge) build the web pages content as static HTML pages so the SEO crawer can index their data.

So if this is the case, would this require me to re-build using `NPM RUN BUILD` for example each time data needs to be updated? (this is based on me hosting this site on a static web host like namecheap) -

or, do other hosts like (popularly mentioned) Netlify, run NUXT GRIDSOME on their backend and constantly re-build the site for you?

I've been in search of clarification on this, any input or documentation you can send me on this subject is really appreciated!

All the best,
W

---

EDIT FROM RESHEARCH

---

So turns out Netlify has something called Automaic Deplaoyment which basically means that - you upload your vue / nuxt / gridsome project to github - then connect that to Netlify - Netlify then builds your project for you and once you push a NEW update to your github it auto created a new dist with your updated github changes

i.e.

netlify has a eventLister type thing for github waiting for your github to be updated so it can re-build your site

---

Still feel this is only half the puzzle but its a start